# HttpServletRequest get query parameters from a GET call

Tags: java, servlets, get

I'm trying to get the query parameter `client_id` from a GET call with a url like this:

```
https://example.com?client_id=aclient-id&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

I'm getting a null value for `clientId` when I try to get the query parameter, any ideas why this is happening?

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
final String clientId = httpRequest.getParameter("client_id");
```

The other calls like `http.getRequestURI()` and `http.getMethod` return the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what the string value of the client id that is actually being sent to the server.  In your example you say `clientId` in your code you're looking for `client_id`, while they make semantic sense to humans, those are different values to a computer.

You can also take a peek at all the parameter values in your HttpServletRequest:

```
httpRequest.getParameterMap()
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `clientId` is the name I give to the Java String, but I'm still getting parameter `client_id`, which is what is coming in the request.